# VS2010/EntityFramework - Is it possible to execute generated sql for a Sqlite database?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sqlite

VS2010/EntityFramework - Is it possible to execute generated sql for a Sqlite database? (like you can for SQL Server).

When I try to do this I only seem to get SQL Server type options re which database to execute the SQL against (even though my Entity Framework design was based on the initial/successful upload from a SQLite database)

EDIT: I can create an entity model ok from import from a sqlite database, BUT when I try to generate SQL code it doesn't seem to be standard sql (perhaps it is Sql Server syntax or something).  And if I try to run the sql it wants to connect me to a sql server database (not the connection I had to the sqlite database I used to create the entity framework model)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [SQLite provider for the Entity Framework](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Comment: I've already got this, and I can create an entity model ok from import from a sqlite database, BUT when I try to generate SQL code it doesn't seem to be standard sql (perhaps it is Sql Server syntax or something)

Answer (score 1):

Try [dotConnect for SQLite](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/download.html).

Comment: I fit into the hobbyist category to some extent & dotConnect has a commercial price against it doesn't it for the Entity Framework feature?  But are you saying the issue is in the provider not VS2010 & you know dotConnect doesn't have this issue (c.f. the sqlite.phxsoftware.com one)?

Comment: All SQL is generated by the provider. Visual Studio and the EF do not generate SQL. So if the SQL is wrong, then either you have a buggy provider, you're using a DB server version not supported by the provider, or you're using the provider incorrectly.

Comment: ok, so Devart has a real point then re giving it I try then is what I'm hearing - thanks

Comment: I have dotConnect loaded.  Seems to allow DB to Class generation, but can't see any way to do Class to DB?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Model First support for SQLite at the moment. We are working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Only professional version of dotConnect offers EF, linq, etc.